# IOS (Objective-C) How to indefinitely change the image in a UITableView Cell from an Array of UIImages

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

How can I make two images interchangeably animate indefinitely in a UITableViewCell?

Update (Solution so far): 
I was able to look into UIImage Animations and here's my current solution

```
NSArray *imagesArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:imageA,imageB,nil];
UIImage *x=[UIImage animatedImageWithImages:imagesArray duration:2.0f];
cell.imageView.image=x;
```

Comment: If you could update your question to show what you have tried, what code you already have, the TableView setup etc. This will help to assure you get an answer to your query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UIKit has everything ready-made for you.

The UIImageView class has built-in frame based animations. You install an array of images in the image view's animationImages array, configure the timing of the animation, and then start it animating with a startAnimating call. It's well documented in the Xcode docs in the Animating Images section of the UIImageView class reference.

You should create a custom subclass of UITableViewCell that has an image view in it and configure the image view to run a continuously repeating frame animation.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `NSTimer` class. When you create the timer, you'll specify a target object, a selector, a time interval, and whether or not the timer repeats. Basically, you can have the timer send a message to the view controller in charge of your table every so often. When the view controller receives the message, that method should change the image in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am not following what you want to do, but one simple solution would be to just use the properties `animationImages` and `animationDuration` on `UIImageView` in your cell. Have a look at the documentation here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImageView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImageView/animationImages

You basically just provide an array of images and set the duration to an appropriate length so that each of your images displays for 2/3 of a second as requested.

Comment: I guess our answers "crossed in the mail?"